# The meaning of "Toss a card and keep on rolling"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Could anyone please make the meaning of the highlighted sentence in the following text clear to me?

[*Each player gets only a few seconds to make a move, and a three-minute limit keeps matches quick and exciting. Playable cards are highlighted each round so you don’t waste seconds scanning your hand. **Toss that “Reverse” and keep on rolling!***](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/lets-play-uno/id1474387228)

The text is from the description of the game "UNO". Here is a description of the game from the same source:

*A family staple since 1971, UNO is that rarest of games: simple, strategic, and equally fun for everyone in the family. Here’s how the mobile version breathes new life into this time-honored classic.*

Comment: Could you please invest some time researching whatever it is that you have questions about? For example, you could've googled "reverse uno", "keep on rolling", "toss". Do that next time. Google each word separately, and then phrases, until it makes sense. If it still doesn't, ask here, and include all that research and how it does/doesn't make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the game?

If so you will know that "reverse" is one of the playable cards in the game.

You also know that in UNO™ you play cards from your hand onto a pile in the middle of the game.  This could be called "tossing" a card onto the pile.

"Keep on rolling" is a vague slangy expression meaning "Keep going and having fun". It appears in some rock and roll songs:

> I've been rolling in my Cadillac
>   Keep on rolling, never coming back
>   In my pocket there's a lot of dough
>   And I don't know where I'm gonna go

It says you can play the game quickly on your mobile, so you can "keep on rolling".